# Booting loop after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

I installed Ubuntu in my notebook in a HDD separated from my Windows(in the SSD) and right now I'm unable to boot neither of the two. It loops restarting my system until it show me a message saying that all boot options aren't working.
I used a USB with grub to boot the system and send this(in this part only shows the Ubuntu partition)

Tried Boot-Repair and it says that its repaired but .. no.
here is the pastebin: http://paste2.org/EdMJFgVM

Secure Boot : Disabled, using CMOS + UEFI (tried the other options, not working)
Boot priority: Tested all the combinations

That's the only info i have, if you need something tell me please.

Answer (score 1):

### Diagnosis

I'm not sure how you got to where it is now, but your current configuration is unworkable for booting Windows. It should be repairable, but there are several options for this, and I can't say which will be easiest. To help you understand what's going on, here's my list of observations:

- You have two disks:

  - `/dev/sda` is a 223.6 GiB GPT disk with two partitions, both of which are Windows-related. The partitions cover all but about 0.5 MiB of the disk but do *not* include the all-important [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is needed for booting any EFI-based computer in EFI mode. The fact that the disk is GPT means that Windows will boot *only* in EFI mode from this disk.
  - `/dev/sdb` is a 931.5 GiB GPT disk with five partitions, all of which are Linux-related. The partitions cover the first ~220 MiB of the disk, so a lot of it is unallocated. One partition is a [BIOS Boot Partition,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) which can be part of a BIOS-mode boot of Linux from an EFI disk, and this appears to be set up correctly. This will *not* help in booting Windows. There's no sign of an ESP on this disk.
- BIOS-mode GRUB seems to be set up correctly; the GRUB MBR code resides where it should, there's a BIOS Boot partition, and there's a `grub.cfg` file. My suspicion is that the system is not booting because the firmware is not set to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode from the hard disk or because it's set to boot from `/dev/sda`, not from `/dev/sdb`. (The firmware's disk identification will not match these Linux names, though.)

In some sense, you should not have been able to get to this condition, since Windows should not have installed to the disk it's on without also creating an ESP. Chances are you either accidentally deleted the ESP or you converted `/dev/sda` from MBR to GPT form. How you got to where you are will affect what recovery path is easiest, which is why I can't say what will be the easiest repair.

### Recommendations

There are quite a few options for repairing this setup. Broadly speaking, you could:

- **Start again** -- After fixing boot-mode issues (see below), you could wipe everything and start from scratch. This is a reasonable option, and may be easier than attempting a repair of the current installations, if these are fresh installations of both OSes. OTOH, it's very important that you understand your boot modes, as noted below, before you attempt a re-installation; otherwise you're likely to end up in the same hole again.
- **Convert from GPT to MBR and install BIOS-mode boot loaders** -- You can use my `gdisk` to convert both disks from GPT to MBR, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) With that done, you could re-run Boot Repair, which might finally get things running. OTOH, you might also need to install a BIOS-mode boot loader for Windows. I'm not sure of the exact procedure for this, and you should ask about it on a Windows forum. This approach is most likely to work if you did a BIOS-mode install of Windows to begin with and accidentally converted `/dev/sda` from MBR to GPT. (This can happen if you use `gdisk` and don't know what you're doing.) This approach is less likely to be optimal if you installed Windows in EFI mode originally (which would include if the computer came with Windows pre-installed and you didn't re-install it), since in that case there will be no hint of a BIOS-mode Windows boot loader on the system.
- **Install EFI-mode boot loaders for both OSes** -- You can create an ESP (which is easy enough; a ~550 MiB ESP will easily fit on `/dev/sdb` and install EFI-mode boot loaders for both Windows and Linux. When booted *in EFI mode,* Boot Repair will do this for Linux, but you'll need to ask on a Windows forum for instructions on installing an EFI-mode boot loader for Windows. (Note that instructions you find on the Web might or might not be appropriate for installing an EFI-mode boot loader. Older instructions, in particular, often assume a BIOS-mode boot.) If you go this route, it's best if you disable your CSM.

It's possible that you wound up in this mess because you enabled your Compatibility Support Module (CSM). (I believe the boot mode you mentioned is "CSM + UEFI," not "CMOS + UEFI.") See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for information on the CSM and why it can create problems. (I *strongly* recommend that you read that page!) In brief, a CSM enables a modern EFI-based computer to boot older ("legacy") BIOS-based OSes. This can be useful, but if used inappropriately, it can create all manner of troubles. Disabling the CSM requires entering your firmware setup utility and adjusting one or more options, which might be called "CSM," "legacy boot support," "BIOS boot mode," or something else entirely. (Sometimes you'd set the "boot mode" to "EFI only" or "UEFI only," for instance.)

With the CSM disabled, the computer should boot *only* in EFI mode, which simplifies things and makes it harder to dig yourself into a hole. People often enable the CSM when they shouldn't because they've created boot media that boot only in BIOS mode; but enabling the CSM then leads them to install in BIOS mode, when an EFI-mode install was in fact more appropriate. In other words, instead of enabling the CSM, they should have fixed their boot media -- a topic that's covered in detail on my page on the CSM.

Comment: First of all sorry for not comment the thread, right now i cant try anything because i have setup the environment in ubuntu for my thesis so, i have to wait like 1 month to try other things, Right know the "patch" that i found was modifiying windows so it shows me the boot options of windows "safe mode, other windows" stuff, when that boot menu shows up you press Escape and then automatically boots ubuntu.
Other info: I have a SSD where my HDD was, and now i have a caddy in my CD bay with the old HDD